# can someone explain to me what respond_to does? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So when one generates scaffodl, the controller automatically creates these blocks(?) like this

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @c }
    end
```

what does this really do and how come it has `format.html` and `format.xml`? What does each do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It defines that the current action will respond to various formats (the action's content can be rendered in many ways, not only plain old HTML).

- If you open your browser and type `/my/path/to/action.html`, it will render HTML (from the template);
- If you type `/my/path/to/action.xml`, it will render XML using `{ render :xml => @c }`. XML will be generated by Rails by calling the `to_xml` method on the `@c` variable;
- However, if you point to `/my/path/to/action.json`, it will throw a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses the `MIME type` of the request determined by the `Accept` header or format (`/controller/action/5.xml`; `/controller/action/5.html`; `/controller/action/5.json`; etc… ) to determine the response format of the controller action that maps to the requested url.

This way rails can automagically render different content formats for many types of requests to the same controller action.